# unable to load gem cocoa pods while creating repo

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, cocoapods

rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 35 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

from /Users/divyam.shukla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'

```
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

I am getting this error.

Comment: Doesn't look like CocoaPods is installed correctly. You might try `gem uninstall cocoapods; gem install cocoapods` (just to make sure you remove any remnants.

Comment: hi the cocoapods are installed correctly but when i am creating the repo for this version it gives an error and this is the error.

Comment: This tutorials help me:http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2013/02/01/troubleshooting-cocoapods-installation/    http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hey I had the same problem that you have, I solve it following the next steps:

(I strongly recommend to use rvm to manage ruby versions)

1. Remove cocoapods using `gem uninstall cocoapods`
2. Install **rvm**, to do this I followed this steps
   https://rvm.io/rvm/install
3. After that reinstall cocoapods using `gem install cocoapods`
4. run `pod setup`

And after that everything works like a charm!.

You could notice that **I didn't use** `sudo`.

Hope it could helps you.

**EDIT:** If you have a slow internet connection it could take several minutes, to check the progress or steps use `pod setup --verbose`

Comment: `gem uninstall cocoapods; gem install cocoapods; pod setup` worked for me. Didn't need to mess with rvm. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I just ran this **without doing any changes** using `rvm`.

I do have rvm version: `rvm 1.25.30 (stable)`.

**Step 1:** `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

**Step 2:** `gem install cocoapods`

**Step 3:** `pod setup`

**Make sure not to install with `sudo`.**

Comment: Make sure not to install with sudo? why?

Answer (score 0):

do this : 
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods