# mac os sierra pod install command failure

Tags: cocoapods, macos-sierra

After moving to Mac OS Sierra, I'm facing problem to install cocoapods.

1. Every time I run `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre` every thing installed well, but while trying to install a pod, the terminal stack on Setting up CocoaPods master repo. Already updated the system with `sudo gem update --system` and still got the same issue, searched online to found old answers to use `pod install --verbose  Ss`. I found in THIS answer fail again tells to install it manually.
   NOTE: I have the latest version of 'Command Line Tools'. Any suggestion or how to install master repo manually?
2. Even when empty pod (i.e. without any pod name in it) is installed it gives

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 66 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/my_name/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `'
```

Comment: Use small paragraphs and make your question readable.

Comment: _I found in THIS answer_ - WHAT answer? You did not include a link.

Answer (score 8):

Follow the instruction given below. It may help you.

1. check pod version using command given below

   > pod --version
2. if there is any version installed remove it by using the command

   > sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
3. restart your mac and reinstall again using the command

   > sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

it will be security problem with mac os Sierra, i will try it and it will work for me . u can try it.
[unable to load gem cocoa pods while creating repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042102/unable-to-load-gem-cocoa-pods-while-creating-repo)